# Не сохраняются обновления Yii2

Tags: yii2

Где может быть ошибка? 
print_r($game->getErrors());
выдает 
Array ( )

```html
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $game = Game::findOne($id);
        $screen = Screenshots::find()->where(['game_id' => $id])->All();
        
        if (!isset($game, $screen)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("The game was not found.");
        }        
        $game->scenario = 'update';
        foreach ($screen as $key) {
          $key->scenario = 'update';
        }        
        
        if (Model::loadMultiple([$game, $screen], Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($game->validate() && $screen->validate()) {
                $game->save(false);

                foreach ($screen as $key) {
                  $key->save(false);
                }
                return $this->redirect(['game/view', 'id' => $id]);
            }
        }        
        return $this->render('update', [
            'game' => $game,
            'screen' => $screen,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$game->save(false);
```

Ответ тут. Зачем ставить false? Ты уверен в том что false нужно тебе ставить вездеи понимаешь ли ты вообще зачем ставится false?

А зачем return?? Просто render и все.

```
$this->render('update', [
            'game' => $game,
            'screen' => $screen,
        ]);
```

Comment: `return` нужен. А так да, ошибка в том что `save` с флагом `false` не выполняет валидацию.

Comment: если ответ правильный, его нужно отметить.